# How do I define a friend class from the global namespace in another namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, global, friend

In a previous Q&A ([How do I define friends in global namespace within another C++ namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207219/how-do-i-define-friends-in-global-namespace-within-another-c-namespace)), the solution was given for making a friend *function* definition within a namespace that refers to a function in the global namespace.

I have the same question for *classes*.

```
class CBaseSD;

namespace cb {
class CBase
{
    friend class ::CBaseSD; // <-- this does not work!?
private:
    int m_type;
public:
    CBase(int t) : m_type(t) {};
};
}; // namespace cb

class CBaseSD
{
private:
    cb::CBase*  m_base;
public:
    CBaseSD(cb::CBase* base) : m_base(base) {};
    int* getTypePtr()
    { return &(m_base->m_type); };
};
```

If I put CBaseSD into a namespace, it works; e.g.,
    friend class SD::CBaseSD;
but I have not found an incantation that works for the global namespace.

I am compiling with g++ 4.1.2.

Comment: GCC seems to complain about the unneeded semicolon after the closing brace of namespace cb

Comment: Manuel is right its working fine even in vc++ 2003 , so 1+.

Comment: Can you remove the semi colon from the closing brace of the namespace and include the warning you get?

Comment: Works fine with g++ 4.0 and 4.2 (on Mac).

Comment: Work fine with g++ 4.1.2 on Linux (after removing the superfluous semicolon).  I'm voting for a pilot error.

Comment: Works with and without the semicolon after closing brace of namespace on g++ 4.4.1.

Comment: I had the same question, and it was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821290/c-global-extern-c-friend-cant-reach-private-member-on-namespaced-class

Answer (score 2):

As stated in some of the comments below the question, the code in the question appears to work with me (Linux-Ubuntu-16.04, gcc version 5.4.0), provided that the friend class was **forward-declared**.

In pursuit of an answer, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492062/why-does-a-c-friend-class-need-a-forward-declaration-only-in-other-namespaces/25157623) that both explains proper technique for making friend class of a global namespace and answers why it needs to be declared the way it does. It is a nice thread because it references the standard.

As stated earlier, the class of a global namespace must be **forward declared** before it can be used as a friend class to a class within a namespace.

Answer (score -1):

add the forward declaration like below

```
namespace {  
  // anonymous namespace declaration
  class CBaseSD;
}

then your normal

friend class CBaseSD;// no need of ::
```

works in CBase

Comment: forward declarations are by default in file scope. We can just declare in global scope :-)

Comment: Don't confuse anonymous & global namespaces