# Why does a C++ friend class need a forward declaration only in other namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend, forward-declaration

Suppose I have a class `F` that should be friend to the classes `G` (in the global namespace) and `C` (in namespace `A`).

- to be friend to `A::C`, `F` must be forward declared.
- to be friend to `G`, no forward declaration of `F` is necessary.
- likewise, a class `A::BF` can be friend to `A::C` without forward declaration

The following code illustrates this and compiles with GCC 4.5, VC++ 10 and at least with one other compiler.

```
class G {
    friend class F;
    int g;
};

// without this forward declaration, F can't be friend to A::C
class F;

namespace A {

class C {
    friend class ::F;
    friend class BF;
    int c;
};

class BF {
public:
    BF() { c.c = 2; }
private:
    C c;
};

} // namespace A

class F {
public:
    F() { g.g = 3; c.c = 2; }
private:
    G g;
    A::C c;
};

int main()
{
    F f;
}
```

To me this seems inconsistent. Is there a reason for this or is it just a design decision of the standard?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`C++` Standard `ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)`

**7.3.1.2  Namespace member definitions**

*Paragraph 3*

> Every name first declared in a
>   namespace is ***a member of that
>   namespace***.  If a friend declaration in
>   a non-local class first declares a
>   class or function 
>   (this implies that the name of the class or function is unqualified) the friend class
>   or function is a member of the
>   innermost enclosing namespace.
>
> ```
> // Assume f and g have not yet been defined.
> void h(int);
> template <class T> void f2(T);
> namespace A {
>    class X {
>    friend void f(X);  //  A::f(X) is a friend
>       class Y {
>          friend void g();  //  A::g is a friend
>          friend void h(int);  //  A::h is a friend
>          //  ::h not considered
>          friend void f2<>(int);  //  ::f2<>(int) is a friend
>       };
>    };
>    //  A::f, A::g and A::h are not visible here
>    X x;
>    void g() { f(x); }  // definition of A::g
>    void f(X) { /* ... */}  // definition of A::f
>    void h(int) { /* ... */ }  // definition of A::h
>    //  A::f, A::g and A::h are visible here and known to be friends
> }
> ```

Your `friend class BF;` is a declaration of `A::BF` in namespace A rather than global namespace. You need the global prior declaration to avoid this new declaration.

Comment: A reasonable person might ask why it does not suffice to write "`friend class ::F;`" (as shown in the OP's code), thus explicitly pushing `F` into the global namespace.  I think the answer is along the lines of "a qualified-id never declares a new name" but am not sure exactly what the standard says on this point.

Comment: @Zack That was my initial question, too: Why do I need to add a forward declaration, when I move a class in another namespace? But there are a couple of discussions already on this topic (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059665/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368642/).  Seems that not needing a forward declaration in the same scope is a convenience that has been granted by the authors of the standard.

Comment: All this C++ standard is cool but there comes Microsoft with its MSVC compiler where even with conformance mode enabled, you can just write `friend class F` without `::` and you don't even have to forward-declare `class F;` It will compile anyway ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 7):

Let's take into account these 3 code lines from your sample:

```
1. friend class F; // it creates "friend declaration", (that's not the same as ordinary forward declaration

2. class F; // without this forward declaration, F can't be friend to A::C <-- this is ordinary forward declaration

3. friend class ::F; // this is qualified lookup (because of ::), so it needs previous declaration, which you provide in line 2.
```

**C++ standard in paragraph 7.3.1.2, point 3 ( Namespace member definitions)** says:

> The friend declaration does not by itself make the name visible to
>   unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or qualified lookup (3.4.3). [ Note: The
>   name of the friend will be visible in its namespace if a matching
>   declaration is provided at namespace scope (either before or after the
>   class definition granting friendship). —end note ]

And line 2 follows exactly what standard requires.

All confusion is because "friend declaration" is *weak*, you need to provide solid forward declaration for further usage.

Answer (score 2):

Because it wouldn't make sense to be able to declare something in the global namespace if you're inside a `namespace {}` block. The reason `friend class BF;` works is that it acts like an implicit forward declaration.