# Overloaded arithmetic operators on a template causing an unresolved external error

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, unresolved-external

Let's say I have this class:

in **Vector4.h**:

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class Vector4
{
public:
T X;
T Y;
T Z;
T W;

Vector4();
Vector4(T X, T Y, T Z, T W);
~Vector4();

friend Vector4<T> operator*(const Vector4<T>& l, const Vector4<T>& r);
};

#include "Vector4.inl"
```

and in **Vector4.inl**:

```
template<typename T>
Vector4<T>::Vector4()
{
X = 0;
Y = 0;
Z = 0;
W = 0;
}

template<typename T>
Vector4<T>::Vector4(T X, T Y, T Z, T W)
{
   this->X = X;
   this->Y = Y;
   this->Z = Z;
   this->W = W;
}

template<typename T>
Vector4<T>::~Vector4()
{

}

template<typename T>
Vector4<T> operator*(const Vector4<T>& l, const Vector4<T>& r)
{
     return(Vector4<T>(l.X * r.X, l.Y * r.Y, l.Z * r.Z, l.W * r.W));
}
```

And when I use it somewhere like this:

```
Vector4<float> a, b;
a = a * b;
```

it gives me a **LNK2019 unresolved external symbol**
What am I doing wrong?Is the syntax I'm using incorrect?

Comment: Really no need to use `friend` when it's not accessing private members.

Comment: *What* symbol is undefined?

Comment: Can you give us the full linker error?

Comment: The full linker error is: Error 4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class Vector4<float> __cdecl operator*(class Vector4<float> const &,class Vector4<float> const &)"referenced in function _main C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\LocalStorage\Untitled\Engine\_MAIN.obj

Comment: Are you building two projects that are statically linked together?

Comment: Yes I am, Vector4 is in my Base project which is a lib and I'm using it in the main one that is an exe

Comment: Vector4.inl is included at the end of Vector4.h and I've linked Base.lib(where Vector4 is) in my main project.

Comment: I think your friend function declaration doesn't declare a template and therefore doesn't match the definition.

Comment: @DYP could you explain further?What do you mean?It's inside the class brackets.Isn't this proper syntax?And in the definition you don't need to put Vector4<T>:: before the name because it's a friend operator, right?

Comment: @DyP I agree that it isn't declaring the correct function to be a friend, but shouldn't it not matter? He is accessing only public members in the non-friended function.

Comment: @Bogomil I think you cannot friend a specialization of a template that has not been declared yet. Either friend the whole function template `template<typename U> friend Vector4<U> operator*(...)` or use forward-declarations.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I think the problem is overload resolution choosing the non-template `operator*` declared in the friend function declaration inside `Vector4` over the non-template function `operator*` declared&defined in "Vector4.inl" (those are two distinct functions).

Comment: @DyP oh man you are totally right. Because you have to predeclare friend classes, I didn't realize that friend functions declarations acts as function declarations. That's...well, weirdly inconsistent. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492062/why-does-a-c-friend-class-need-a-forward-declaration-only-in-other-namespaces]

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments, your friend function declaration

```
friend Vector4<T> operator*(const Vector4<T>& l, const Vector4<T>& r);
```

declares a non-template function in the global namespace. When you instantiate e.g. `Vector4<int>`, the function

```
Vector4<int> operator*(const Vector4<int>& l, const Vector4<int>& r)
```

is declared. Note that it's **not** a function template. (Also see [temp.friend])

Your `Vector4.inl` then declares and defines a function template

```
template<typename T>
Vector4<T> operator*(const Vector4<T>& l, const Vector4<T>& r)
```

i.e. an overload of the former function. In the expression `a * b`, overload resolution chooses the non-template `operator*` over the template version (see [over.match.best]/1). This results in a linker error, as the non-template function hasn't been defined.

---

As I've almost fooled myself, a short remark:

```
template<typename T>
Vector4<T> operator*(const Vector4<T>& l, const Vector4<T>& r);
```

As this operator is a free function (a non-member function), these two lines declare a function template, much like

```
template<typename T>
Vector4<T> wup();
```

On the other hand,

```
template<typename T>
Vector4<T> Vector4<T>::operator*(const Vector4<T>& r)
{ /* ... */ }
```

defines a member function (non-template) of a class template (`Vector4`).

---

One solution is to use forward-declarations and befriend only a specific specialization:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector4;

template<typename T>
Vector4<T> operator*(const Vector4<T>& l, const Vector4<T>& r);


template<typename T>
class Vector4
{
public:
    T X;
    T Y;
    T Z;
    T W;

    Vector4();
    Vector4(T X, T Y, T Z, T W);
    ~Vector4();

    // compiler knows of some function template `operator*`,
    // can name an specialization:
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~vvv
    friend Vector4<T> operator*<T>(const Vector4<T>& l, const Vector4<T>& r);
};

template<typename T>
Vector4<T>::Vector4()
{
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
    Z = 0;
    W = 0;
}

template<typename T>
Vector4<T>::Vector4(T X, T Y, T Z, T W)
{
   this->X = X;
   this->Y = Y;
   this->Z = Z;
   this->W = W;
}

template<typename T>
Vector4<T>::~Vector4()
{}

template<typename T>
Vector4<T> operator*(const Vector4<T>& l, const Vector4<T>& r)
{
     return(Vector4<T>(l.X * r.X, l.Y * r.Y, l.Z * r.Z, l.W * r.W));
}

int main()
{
    Vector4<float> a, b;
    a = a * b;
}
```

Another solution would be to friend the whole `operator*` template instead of a single specialization:

```
template<typename U>
friend Vector4<U> operator*(Vector4<U> const&, Vector4<U> const&);
```

Comment: Great answer with good explanation and examples. I forgot to add the <T> argument list after the "operator*" in the class declaration, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change the code to nonfriended version:

1. code inside class definition:

   ```
   Vector4<T> operator*(Vector4<T> const & r);
   ```
2. code of operator*. It is changed to take only one parameter.

   ```
   template<typename T>
   Vector4<T> Vector4<T>::operator*(Vector4<T> const &r)
   {
        return(Vector4<T>(this->X * r.X, this->Y * r.Y, this->Z * r.Z, this->W * r.W));
   }
   ```

Comment: This is a non-member function; `operator*` can be declared either as a member function (taking one parameter) or a non-member function (taking two parameters). Both "errors" you mention aren't actually errors.

Comment: my mistake, what is the purpose in using the friend operator? i've succeeded in C++11 in delaring one argument operator* without friending it.

Comment: Here, the purpose is unclear. Normally you'd use the `friend` specifier if you want a function (or class) accessing `private` or `protected` members. It isn't necessary here. Note that using `friend` inside a class is a declaration and can declare new functions / classes, which leads to the error in the OP.

Comment: Yup, this is also a solution; though AFAIK, non-member functions are preferred for operators because of symmetry: for non-member (binary) operators, you can choose the type of the left hand side (like for `5 == Vector4<int>()`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove `friend` from your declaration of `operator*` in the .h file

it should look like this:

```
Vector4<T> operator*(const Vector4<T>& r);
```

Then in the .inl file operator* should look like this:

```
Vector4<T> Vector4<T>::operator*(const Vector4<T>& r){
     return(Vector4<T>(X * r.X, Y * r.Y, Z * r.Z, W * r.W));
}
```

The operand on the left hand side of the operator is what called this member function.

Comment: The thing you want to change the friend declaration into is ill-formed. Typo? (like, only one parameter?)