# Why LNK1120 & LNK2019 appears in case of template and friend function

Tags: c++, class, templates, friend-function

I have compiled the first version of code in Turbo-C and it compiles without any error. But when I compile this in Visual Studio or plain g++ from CommandLine, I get errors mentioned down in the post.

I did searched over internet and read some of the StackOverflow questions & MSDN LNK1120 problem docs.  I found a way to fix the below code. However, didn't got the reason clearly. How can just a definition gets rid of that error. Syntactically the error prone code also look fine.

```
1) Error    2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   

2) Error    1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl  

totalIncome(class Husband<int> &,class Wife<int> &)" (?totalIncome@@YAXAAV?
$Husband@H@@AAV?$Wife@H@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Note: Please watch out for arrows in program. I've explicitly put them. So, might not go through the complete program.

**Error Prone Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> class Wife;           // Forward declaration of template    

template<typename T>
        class Husband{
        friend void totalIncome(Husband<T> &hobj, Wife<T> &wobj);

        public:
            Husband() = default;
            Husband(T new_salary): salary{new_salary} {}

        private:
            T salary;
        };

template<typename T>
        class Wife{
        friend void totalIncome(Husband<T> &hobj, Wife<T> &wobj);

        public:
        Wife() = default;
        Wife(T new_salary): salary{new_salary} {}

        private:
            T salary;
        };

template<typename T> void totalIncome(Husband<T> &hobj, Wife<T> &wobj)   __
{                                                                         |
    cout << "Total Income of Husband & Wife: ";                           |
    cout << hobj.salary + wobj.salary;                                    |
}                                                                         |
                                                                        ---
int main()
{
    Husband<int> h(40000);
    Wife<int> w(90000);

    totalIncome(h, w);

    return 0;
}
```

but in the below case by just moving the definition up in the class, it runs perfectly fine. Why whats the reason?

**Fixed Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> class Wife;           // Forward declaration of template    

template<typename T>
        class Husband{
        friend void totalIncome(Husband<T> &hobj, Wife<T> &wobj);

        public:
            Husband() = default;
            Husband(T new_salary): salary{new_salary} {}

        private:
            T salary;
        };

template<typename T>
        class Wife{
        friend void totalIncome(Husband<T> &hobj, Wife<T> &wobj)  __
        {                                                           |              
           cout << "Total Income of Husband & Wife: ";              | -- definition moved up here          
           cout << hobj.salary + wobj.salary;                       |             
        }                                                         __|

        public:
        Wife() = default;
        Wife(T new_salary): salary{new_salary} {}

        private:
            T salary;
        };

/*
template<typename T> void totalIncome(Husband<T> &hobj, Wife<T> &wobj)   __
{                                                                         |
    cout << "Total Income of Husband & Wife: ";                           |
    cout << hobj.salary + wobj.salary;                                    |
}                                                                         |
                                                                        ---
*/

int main()
{
    Husband<int> h(40000);
    Wife<int> w(90000);

    totalIncome(h, w);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `friend void totalIncome(Husband<T> &hobj, Wife<T> &wobj);` declares a function in global scope, but you define a function **template** *with the same name* later. A function template is not a function, hence those two entities are not identical. There will be two function declarations (one from the friend function, and one from a function template specialization), and overload resolution chooses the undefined friend function. Try forward-declaring the function template before the friend-declaration.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17842450

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22585725

Comment: @dyp nope they are different questions. Couldn't infer the solution by looking at those problems.

Comment: @dyp could you please write an answer elaborating more on problem. Didn't understood it. Which functions are you are referring to?

Comment: The questions are not exact duplicates, hence I didn't close your question. The underlying issue of all three is the same, though. In the first link, the culprit is `operator*`, whereas it is `totalIncome` in your question. The fact that one is an operator is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's cut this down to a minimal example that reproduces the issue:

```
template<typename T>
        class Husband{
        friend void totalIncome(Husband<T> &);
        };

template<typename T> void totalIncome(Husband<T> &hobj)
{}

int main()
{
    Husband<int> h;
    totalIncome(h);
}
```

This leads to a similar linker error. For example, using clang++:

```
/tmp/main-fb41c4.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `totalIncome(Husband&)'
```

---

The underlying issue is the same as the one in [Overloaded arithmetic operators on a template causing an unresolved external error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17841913) and in [Strange behavior of templated `operator<<`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22584040/420683). Hence, I'll base my answer here on my answer from the second question.

---

## Friend function declarations

In the class template `Husband`, there is a friend-declaration of the function `totalIncome`:

```
friend void totalIncome(Husband<T> &);
```

A friend function declaration looks up the name of the declared function (here: `totalIncome`) in the surrounding scopes up to and including the innermost enclosing namespace. If a declaration of that name is found, the declared entity is befriended:

```
class Husband;
void totalIncome(Husband&);             // (A)

class Husband{
    friend void totalIncome(Husband&);  // befriends (A)
};
```

If no declaration of the name is found, **a new function is declared in the innermost enclosing namespace**:

```
class Husband{
    friend void totalIncome(Husband&);  // declares and befriends ::totalIncome
};

void totalIncome(Husband&);             // friend of class Husband
```

If the function is only declared via the friend function declaration (and there is no later declaration in the enclosing namespace), the function can only be found via Argument-Dependent Lookup.

---

## Befriending a function in a class template

The issue in the OP's code is that there is a class template involved:

```
template<typename T>
        class Husband{
        friend void totalIncome(Husband<T> &);
        };
```

The rules stay the same: No declaration of `totalIncome` is found. Since the signature of the friend declaration depends on the template parameter of the class template, **every instantiation of `Husband` will introduce a new function in the enclosing namespace**. (If the friend declaration did not depend on a template parameter, you'd get a *redeclaration* with every instantiation of `Husband`.) For example, if you instantiate `Husband<int>` and `Husband<double>`, you'll get two functions in the global namespace:

```
void totalIncome(Husband<int> &);
void totalIncome(Husband<double> &);
```

Note that these are **two unrelated functions**, much like:

```
void totalIncome(int &);
void totalIncome(double &);
```

---

## Overloading a function with a function template

You can overload an "ordinary" function with a function template:

```
void totalIncome(Husband<int> &);    // (A)

template<typename T>
    void totalIncome(Husband<T> &);  // (B)
```

When calling the function via `Husband<int> x; totalIncome(x);`, the function template will produce an instantiation:

```
void totalIncome<int>(Husband<int> &); // (C), instantiated from (B)
```

And your overload set consists of two functions:

```
void totalIncome(Husband<int> &);       // (A)
void totalIncome<int>(Husband<int> &);  // (C)
```

All things equal, overload resolution will prefer the non-template function (A) over the function template specialization (C).

And this is what happens in the OP's code as well: There is a non-template function introduced by instantiating the class template `Husband`, and an unrelated function template. Overload resolution chooses the non-template function, and the linker complains that it doesn't have a definition.

---

## Various solutions

The simplest solution is to define the friend function inside the class definition:

```
template<typename T>
        class Husband{
        friend void totalIncome(Husband<T> &){
            // code here
        }
        };
```

---

A solution using forward-declarations:

```
template<typename T>
        class Husband;

template<typename T>
        void totalIncome(Husband<T> &);

template<typename T>
        class Husband{
        friend void totalIncome(Husband<T> &);
        };

template<typename T> void totalIncome(Husband<T> &hobj)
{}
```

Here, the compiler can find the forward-declared function template and befriend a specialization of it, instead of declaring a new function. It might be worthwhile explicitly adding the template arguments:

```
template<typename T>
        class Husband{
        friend void totalIncome<T>(Husband<T> &);
        };
```

Since this *enforces* that there is a prior declaration of the function template `totalIncome`.

---

A solution befriending the whole function template:

```
template<typename T>
        class Husband{
        template<typename U>
                friend void totalIncome(Husband<U> &);
        };

template<typename T> void totalIncome(Husband<T> &hobj)
{}
```

In this solution, the friend-declaration declares a **function template**, and the later declaration at namespace scope following the class' definition **redeclares** and defines this function template. All specializations of the function template will be befriended by all instantiations of `Husband`.