# Correct way to implement operator!= for templates outside of class as a free function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, linker-errors, non-member-functions

I have a following template with inner classes in a `map.hpp` file:

```
template<typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T>
class Map {
    // public members of Map ...

    class Iterator {
        //public members of Iterator ...

        friend bool operator!=(const Iterator &i, const Iterator &j) {
            return (i.link != j.link);  
        }

        // private members of iterator ...
        Node * link;
    };
};
#include "map.hxx"   //implementation file for member methods is separate
```

In the `main.cpp` I call the following and so far everything works fine:

```
Map<int, int> x;
// bunch of insertions ...
for (auto it = x.begin; it != x.end(); ++it) {
    // Do something with it ...   
}
```

However, I want to move the friend function out of the `map.hpp` file and into the `map.hxx` file which contains other implementation.

**Q: Is it possible to move the free function to a `.hxx` file and how?**

I tired declaring the function as a friend in the Iterator class and did the following in the implementation file:

```
template<typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T>
bool operator!=(const typename Map<Key_T, Mapped_T>::Iterator & i,
                const typename Map<Key_T, Mapped_T>::Iterator & j) {
    return (i.link != j.link);
}
```

However it failed with:

```
$clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -Wextra -g main.cpp 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "shiraz::operator!=(shiraz::Map<int, int>::Iterator const&, shiraz::Map<int, int>::Iterator const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-3oCRAm.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/596781

Comment: Why are you asking about "syntax" if you have a *linker* error?

Comment: This might as well be a duplicate of [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29062048/420683). Please show us your friend declaration as well.

Comment: The friend declaration was simply `friend bool operator!=(const Iterator &i, const Iterator &j);`

Comment: Well, then please take a look at the question I've linked. It's probably the same issue.

Comment: @dyp what is with that indentation style?

Comment: @dyp thanks, I am looking through the answer and digesting, as I believe there some concepts that are new to me here

Comment: @Yakk I tried to replicate the OP, but I'm not sure the OP even had a consistent or intended style o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `friend` declaration without a corresponding match will inject a new function into the enclosing namespace.  This function can only be found via ADL

The easiest way to do what you want is to leave a stub implementation in the `iterator` class, and have it forward to a "real" function outside.  That keeps the nice ADL-only lookup of `!=`, which solves some thorny overload problems easily.  The helper function can simply be a `template<class Iterator>` and be friended more normally and have a narrow implementation, and not be found via ADL but rather with a fully qualified lookup.  Or it could be a static member function of the enclosing map.

```
template<typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T>
class Map {
  class Iterator;
  static bool it_equal( Iterator const&, Iterator const& );
  class Iterator {
    friend class Map;
    friend bool operator!=(const Iterator &i, const Iterator &j) {
      return !Map::it_equal(i,j);
    }
    friend bool operator==(const Iterator &i, const Iterator &j) {
      return Map::it_equal(i,j);
    }
    Node * link;
  };
};
```

now your `.hxx` simply implements `bool Map<blah>::it_equal(blah)` and you are done.

Comment: @dyp Mayhap.  Btw, while your answer in the other question is good, it doesn't quite apply to operators.  Creating a free `template<class T> operator!=(T lhs, T rhs)` is highly impolite even if you only specialize it for a few types.  And non-deduced context makes it hard for a sub-type to do that trick too, for while the `!=` will be found, it won't be able to deduce the arguments!  (I have not tested these beliefs)

Comment: Hm. I intended in my answer to explain the problem and provide *various* solutions. I agree most of them won't be nice for a nested type. Don't quite understand the issue you mentioned wrt subtypes.

Comment: @dyp by sub-type I mean nested types.  A problem may be that `template<blah> bool operator!=(Map<blah>::iterator, Map<blah>::iterator)` cannot be deduced without `blah` being explicit -- will `friend` make it explicit?

Comment: *"without `blah` being explicit"* I'm having a hard time understanding your concern. What do you mean with "explicit"? [Like this?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64d2a67ada0b8238) If so, the friend-declaration probably only makes the name of the primary template visible, not specifically the specialization. I'm not quite sure where the Standard specifies this, maybe in [basic.lookup.argdep]/4.2?

Comment: @dyp [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dda04f6484c872d) -- probably same situation.  Specializations do not impact which function is called, and derived types are not deduced.  So you need a `template<class T> void foo(T)`, and in an operator that is rude without SFINAE restriction.  A big advantage of `friend operator` is eliminating that SFINAE annoyance.