# Define friend template method outside namespace

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, operators, friend

I have code with the following basic structure:

```
namespace A{

    template<class T,unsigned DIM>
    class CMyTable{
        ...
            public:
            template<class T,unsigned DIM>
            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const CMyTable<T,DIM>& vec);
        }    

    };

}
```

The initial problem was to get my operator<< outside the namespace A.

I tried this solution : [How do I define friends in global namespace within another C++ namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207219/how-do-i-define-friends-in-global-namespace-within-another-c-namespace)

```
namespace A{

    template<class T,unsigned DIM>
    class CMyTable;
}

template<class T,unsigned DIM>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const CMyTable<T,DIM>& vec);

namespace A{

    template<class T,unsigned DIM>
    class CMyTable{
        ...
            public:
            template<class T,unsigned DIM>
            friend std::ostream& ::operator<<(std::ostream& s, const CMyTable<T,DIM>& vec);
        }    

    };

}

template<class T,unsigned DIM>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const CMyTable<T,DIM>& vec){
// [...]
}
```

I got this error : error C2063: 'operator <<' : not a function inside the class declaration.

```
public:
template<class T,unsigned DIM>
friend std::ostream& ::operator<<(std::ostream& s, const CMyTable<T,DIM>&
```

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ostream overload has to be a `friend` (*needs access to protected members*) then define it inline so that you can use the template arguments passed to the class.

```
namespace A{

    template<class T,unsigned DIM>
    class CMyTable{
        ...
        public:
        // template<class T,unsigned DIM>  // This will shadow otherwise
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const CMyTable<T,DIM>& vec) {
        // [...]
        }
    };
}
```

---

Otherwise completely remove its declaration from the class and namesapce and just define it outside as a templated overload.

**Remember it doesn't have to be friend if it doesn't need access to private or protected elements.**

```
namespace A{
   template<class T,unsigned DIM>
   class CMyTable{
    ...
        public:
    };
}



template<class T,unsigned DIM>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const A::CMyTable<T,DIM>& vec){
// [...]
}
```

---

The third option is to keep it friend but define it inside namespace A

```
namespace A{

    template<class T,unsigned DIM>
    class CMyTable{
        public:
            int i;

        template<class V,unsigned E>
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const CMyTable<V,E>& vec);
    };  

};
//
//

namespace A{

    template<class T,unsigned DIM>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const CMyTable<T,DIM>& vec) {
        s << vec.i;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need my method to be friend. I just don't want to define accessors (even const) in my class.

Comment: @Haimo then what is the problem with defining it inline (inside the class)?

Comment: I want to access to the operator in the global namespace.

Comment: @Haimo Here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=607c22b9a37c4e7aefe63bae25e87bd1-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba

Comment: @Haimo OK if you want not to define it inline for some reason then you have to define it in namespace A. See the edit. Third option.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will check if it will be ok if I use the operator in another namespace (not the global namespace).

Answer (score 0):

Output operator is interface of class really, so, logically, it should be in namespace, where class is declared, but for make your code work, you can use

```
namespace A{

    template<class T,unsigned DIM>
    class CMyTable;
}

// friend is not correct here.
template<class T,unsigned DIM>
/*friend*/ std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const A::CMyTable<T,DIM>& vec);

namespace A{

    template<class T,unsigned DIM>
    class CMyTable{
        ...
            public:
            // choose another names of template pars.
            // or use
            //friend std::ostream& (::operator << <>)(std::ostream& s,
            //const CMyTable<T, DIM>&);
            /*template<class T,unsigned DIM>*/
            template<class U, unsigned D>
            friend std::ostream& (::operator <<)(std::ostream&,
            const CMyTable<U,D>&);
        };
}

template<class T,unsigned DIM>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const A::CMyTable<T,DIM>& vec){
// [...]
}
```

Comment: For the friend, it was a mistake in the post. I edited the post. I changed the names of template arguments but still got the same error: 'operator <<' not a function.

Comment: @Haimo look at code well... Note: `friend std::ostream& **(**::operator <<**)**`

Comment: Sorry, I actually copied/pasted your code. So i added the parenthesis too. But still not work...

Comment: @Haimo, i don't know, why you get this error. Look at example - it works well as you seen.

Comment: Is that possible my compiler (I'm working with VS2005) put me into this ?